# Rich Text Editor does not open on all pages in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: richhtmlfield

When I go in edit pages in Sharepoint 2007 some pages allow me to use Rich Text Editor and some don't.  On the pages that don't, a small yelow traingle with an exclamation point in it appears in the status bar that says error next to it.  The source editor opens but rich text editor doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you copy and paste text into the Content Editor Web Part. I could not tell you why but sometimes when you do this it will create new web part ID's in the Source Code. I would recommend checking the Source of the content editor web part for any additional ID's added to DIV's. You should be able to remove those to stop the javascript errors.